# What is dundee.service process?

Tags: gnome, security, root, process

Does anyone recognize the following process?

```
dundee
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out :)
It's a service [related](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=dundee.service&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any) to "ofono" package.

Reference: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.10/ubuntu-universe-armhf/ofono_1.31-3ubuntu1_armhf.deb.html